# state not updated redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

so I made a notification system with react and redux and added a queue system for preventing to display to much notifications at the same time. It works how it should, but there is only one problem. If add 5 notifications the fifth one should go inside the queue array it does but the components do not relaize that the queue array has now a length of one. If i put again 5 notifications i have 4 on the active array and then 2 notifications inside the queue array, from here it knows that queue array length is now 2. Why is that? Is there a problem with the re-rendering?

My Code:

```
  const notify = useSelector((state) => state.notify);

  const handleClick = () => {
    let notification = {
      iconType: 0,
      title: 'notification.title',
      message: 'notification.message',
      color: '03A65A',
      width: 0,
    };

    showNotifications(notification);
  };

  const timeoutNotification = async (notification: any) => {
    await dispatch(AddActiveItem(notification));
    setTimeout(async () => {
      await dispatch(RemoveActiveItem(notification.id));
      if (notify.queue.length && notify.active.length < 4) {
        let newQueue = notify.queue;
        let pushItem = newQueue.shift();
        await dispatch(SetNewQueue(newQueue));
        timeoutNotification(pushItem);
      }
    }, 120 * notification.message.length);
  };

  const showNotifications = async (notification: any) => {
    notification = {
      id: notify.id,
      iconType: notification.iconType,
      title: notification.title,
      message: notification.message,
      color: notification.color,
      width: notification.width,
    };

    let newId = notify.id + 1;
    dispatch(SetId(newId));

    if (notify.active.length > 3) {
      await dispatch(AddQueueItem(notification));
    } else {
      timeoutNotification(notification);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Redux's `dispatch` is an async function, so the changes made to the Redux state are not visible immediately. If you're sure the state should/will update, simply await the changes..

Comment: disaptch is NOT an async function.

Comment: dispatch itself is not async, as @hellogoodnight pointed out. If the action is async however (thunk) then yes, the dispatch call an be await-ed.

Comment: The action it self is async, but as you see i'm already waiting the dispatches and the state is still updating to late for the rerender...